# Benchmarks for second round CAESAR competitors

Tags: authenticated-encryption, performance, norx, keyak

I'm interested in how the [second round CAESAR competitors](https://competitions.cr.yp.to/caesar-submissions.html) stack up in terms of software performance against each other and against chacha20-poly1305 with both small and large messages. Sadly the only numbers I can find are on their individual websites, and due to most likely different testing methods and hardware those aren't really comparable. Are there any comparison tables or something similar that I just haven't been able to find?

Comment: No, not really. [eBACS](https://bench.cr.yp.to/) is eventually going to be the place for such benchmarks, but not right now.

Comment: @SamuelNeves Hmm alright it will be interesting, how do you expect will norx, keyak and chacha12/20-poly1305 stack up?

Comment: I expect it to go like ChaCha{12,20}-Poly1305 -> NORX6441 -> Lake Keyak, going from fastest to slowest and considering the recommended variants of each on common x86 processors.

Comment: I suspect NORX6444 will be the fastest of all, even on one core, so long as 4-wide SIMD instructions are used.

Answer (score 4):

Benchmarks for 2nd-round candidates are now available at the [eBACS website](https://bench.cr.yp.to/results-caesar.html). There is also an [independent report](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/740) comparing candidates' performance.

Comment: The fastest are usually the AES-NI-using ones when those instructions are available (no surprise). Otherwise OCB, HS1, NORX and Keyak seem to do quite well on eBACS at least.

Comment: OCB also belongs in the AES-NI group.

Comment: Yes, but it seems to be fast even without.